# Cake 2.+ on shared hosting - 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, shared-hosting

Since 2 days I have been trying to get my cake app working (using German 1&1 hosting). The desired address is: http://www.bzalewski.de/k/front. If you open it, you can see, it's there but without images and css. Also this: http://www.bzalewski.de/k/front/art/discover doesn't work (but it does locally with XAMPP. There is no routing, just `ArtController` --> `public function discover()`).

I followed the instructions from this article: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/tim_m/2007/09/20/500-errors-with-1and1-hosting-apache-1-x

My three .htaccess look like this:

**./.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ /k/front/app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) k/front/app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**./app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$   /k/front/app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) /k/front/app/webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**.app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /k/front/app/webroot/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

I would appreciate any help to:

- make controllers work (`art/discover` working)
- make images and other stuff in the `webroot` directory work

Just to mention it: my local XAMPP installation works with standard .htaccess files without any problems.

Comment: It's incredible that nobody knows an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in the root .htaccess (the htaccess in /k/front/ folder) after RewriteEngine On:

```
RewriteBase /k/front/
```

Edit : I did not see that you put /k/front/ everywhere in the htaccess

Then add  RewriteBase / with you version of the htaccess
OR   add  RewriteBase /k/front/ with the default htaccess (without /k/front/ in the RewriteRules )

Comment: even worse? ouch. I'm pretty sure RewriteBase is the key here.

Comment: Each time I have problem like this, I end up creating a file test.php in the root directory of my website (so here something/k/front/test.php) and I try a simple rule : .* /test.php and a rewriteBase / then I try with or without the first slash behind test.php, then with some folder before (k/front/test.php) and again with a different rewriteBase.

Comment: Yes you are right but I don't understand fully how CakePHP maps the paths and that may be the problem. I guess I gonna call the support of the provider. I tried all combinations I found on the Internet and nothing works (500 error, 404 error and so on)